# spring-boot-devtools maven jar not found

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I need to use spring boot devtools to force reload of static resource during dev time.

I added follow code to my pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

but maven did not found the dependecy,

I need to add respoitory uri?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not using a parent pom nor defined `<DependencyManagement>` there, then you should identify the version of jar you want to use.

likes:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>    
    <optional>true</optional>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

You can check out http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-devtools to see which version you would like to use.

Comment: same result with version.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little bit confused. By saying 'maven did not found the dependecy', did you mean maven cannot download the jar, or you mean the auto reload doesn't work?

Comment: The first. Maven can not download the jar. Both dependecy and version are red.  The error is 'Dependency 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:1.5.10.RELEASE' not found'

Comment: I think there's an issue on maven repository. I install it manually. It's stupid lose hours for this kind of problem if there is a workaround solve it.

Comment: Looks like the error message is given by IDEA? You can try running `mvn verify` directly, see what is maven error message.

Comment: IDEA need be configured as "Auto import" pom changes, or you have to manually import after modified pom.

Answer (score 0):

What worked in my project me was adding the dependency inside the tag `dependencyManagement`

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```